# How can I make a parent instantiate its child?

Tags: c++

I have a parent class test with child classes that are sub-tests.  When I call test->run() I want to run all my sub tests.  The code below does not work b.c. the child class is not recognized in the parent class.

```
using namespace std;
  class test
    {
    protected:
      short verbosity_;
    public:
      void setVerbosity(short v)
        {
        if((v==0 || v==1 || v==2)) 
          {
          verbosity_ = v;
          }
        else 
          {
          cout << " Verbosity Level Invalid " << endl;
          }
        }
      void run()
        {
        natives natives_1; // this does not work
      }
    };
  class natives : public test 
    {
    public:
      natives()
        {
        this->run();
        }
      void run()
       {
       testInts<short>();
       testInts<int>();
       testInts<long>();
       testInts<unsigned short>();
       testInts<unsigned int>();
       testInts<unsigned long>();
       }         
    protected:
      template<class T> void testFloats()
        {
        }
      template<class T> void testInts()
        {
        short passState, bitDepth;
        T failMax, pow2 = 1, minValue = 0, maxValue = 0, bitCount = 0, failValue = 0;  
        const char* a = typeid(T).name();
        bool signedType = ((*a == 't') || (*a == 'j') || (*a == 'm'));
        while(pow2 > 0)
          {
          pow2 *= 2;
          bitCount++;
          }
        maxValue = pow2-1;
        failValue = pow2;
        int native1 = bitCount;
        int native2 = sizeof(T)*8;
        int native3 = numeric_limits<T>::digits;  
        if( !signedType )
          {
          native1++;
          native3++;
          }       
        if(verbosity_>=1) cout << endl << "**********\n" << reportType(a) << "\n**********" << endl << endl;
        if ((native1 == native2) && (native1 == native3))
          {
          if(verbosity_>=1)cout << "Correlation:\t\tPass: " << native1 << endl ;
          if(verbosity_>=2)
          {
            cout << "--Algorithm:\t\t" << native1 << endl;
            cout << "--Sizeof:\t\t" << native2 << endl;
            cout << "--Reported:\t\t" << native3 << endl;
            cout << "----Max Value:\t\t" << maxValue << endl;
            cout << "----Max+1\t\t" << failValue << endl;
            } 
         else
            {
            }
          }
        else
          {
          cout << "Correlation:\t\tFail" << endl ;
          }
        }
      string reportType(const char* c1)
        { 
        string s1;
        switch(*c1)
          {
          case 't':
            s1 = "Unsigned short";
            break;
          case 'j':
            s1 = "Unsigned int";
            break;
          case 'm':
            s1 = "Unsigned long";
            break;
          case 's':
            s1 = "Short";
            break;
          case 'i':
            s1 = "Int";
            break;
          case 'l':
            s1 = "Long";
            break;
          default:
            s1 = "Switch failed";
          }
        return s1;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better way to do it would be to make a pure virtual function called `run` in the `test` class, and then the tests of the subclass will implement it and those will be run when you call `run` on an instance of the subclass.

For instance:

```
class Test {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;

    void setVerbosity(short v) {
        if((v==0 || v==1 || v==2)) 
            verbosity_ = v;
        else
            cout << " Verbosity Level Invalid " << endl;
    }
};

class Natives : public Test {
public:
    void run() {
        // do all the tests....
    }
};
```

Then you can do

```
Natives n;
n.run();
```

And they will still be run when you do it through a `Test*` (or `Test&`):

```
Test* t = new Natives;
t->run(); // runs Natives::run
```

You might also be able to use CRTP here but I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: It just makes more sense to run all the test from the parent class...not one of the sub-classes

Comment: @stack.user.1 why does natives need to inherit from test?

Comment: But yea...I will probably do that...as an easy way to do this from the parent class does not seem readily available

Comment: Right now only for the verbosity...and conceptually it makes sense...Test and Sub-test....Clases and Sub-classes

Comment: @stack.user.1 if natives is a subclass of test, then natives must know how to run it's own test, not the other way around. Also it doesn't matter who 'runs' the tests, the user won't be able to tell who's doing what anyway since the syntax will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Compositor pattern

```
class Test {

std::vector<Test> subTests;

public:
void addSubTest(Test t) {
    subTests.add(t);
}

virtual bool doTest() = 0;

void run() {
   for(int i=0; i< subTests.size; ++i) {
       subTests[i].doTest();
   }
   this->doTest();
}
```

Comment: what does .add(t) do...what is add...is this user defined or in a library?

Comment: @stack.user.1 this is C# code incompletely converted to C++ code, and it has become a hybrid between the two, invalid in both.